# How can a task be scheduled in Java to occur at midnight, even if a leap second has just occurred?

Tags: java, time, leap-second

First, definition of "occur at midnight" is that when task is run, `new DateTime()` or similar will show 00:00:00 or later for the time portion when converted to a human readable format. Important point is that it must not show 23:59:59 of the previous day.

A common way to achieve this would be to calculate how many milliseconds are between now and the desired point in time, and then use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute the task at the correct time. However, when a leap second is inserted this will result in the task running a second early (or a few milliseconds early depending on how the leap second is 'smeared' and when you scheduled the task):

```
Runnable task = ...
long numberOfMillisUntilMidnight = ...
ScheduledExecutorService executor = ...

// task runs too early when leap seconds are inserted
executor.schedule(task, numberOfMillisUntilMidnight, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The reason is that `executor.schedule()` is based on `System.nanoTime()` which obviously ignores the leap seconds. I guess what I need is some scheduler based on "run at this time" rather than "run after this amount of time".

For those who are interested, the reason the task must run at midnight related to the fact that all events in my system must be categorized according to which day they occurred on, and in so far as is possible, this needs to be in sync with another system. Of course it would be better if the other system stamped each event with what day it is, but we are not there.

Comment: Does it really matter if it runs a second one way or the other?

Comment: Regarding if it really matters, from a business perspective, yes, but from a technical perspective, no, because I could just write code that says "if it's not midnight yet, just schedule the task again instead of executing it". But this seems inelegant. Regarding Crowder's suggestion, that would work, but again it seems inelegant, and if my application has events that happen between 00:00:00 and 00:00:01 then these will be incorrectly reported as having occurred on the wrong day, which will cause reconciliation issues between 2 systems for 24 hours which have to be looked at manually.

Comment: The task could check, when it runs, that the hour is 0, otherwise sleep for a second.

Comment: But what is the underlying requirement, the real reason it must/should/ought to be midnight? Please give some more context.

Comment: Why do you say that `System.nanoTime()` ignores leap seconds? I think the contrary is true because it just counts elapsed seconds (and hence also a SI-second elapsed). Another thing is how you display it. Here Java-8 does NOT support leap seconds but blindly relies on OS-clock (which usually ignores leap seconds). By the way: The expression `System.currentTimeMillis()` is much more subject to clock changes than `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild: by ignore, I meant that System.nanoTime() does not adjust itself according to leap seconds. Yes the OS-clock ignores leap seconds, but assuming the machine is connected to an external NTP server then it's a good bet that the clock will suffer a change of 1 second around the time of the leap second, so colloquially you could say that the system clock observed the leap second.

Comment: You should not care about how to display and interprete timestamp formats showing 00:00:00 etc.but care more about which kind of clock your system and the other system to be synchronized use. Make sure both systems use the same clock (best the same NTP-clock or any other kind of server-side clock).

Comment: Correct is: `System.nanoTime()` is sensible for elapsed leap seconds but insensitive for OS-clock-adjustments induced by leap seconds.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess what I need is some scheduler based on "run at this time" rather than "run after this amount of time"

That would be the all-singing, all-dancing solution. But:

> First, definition of "occur at midnight" is that when task is run, new DateTime() or similar will show 00:00:00 **or later** for the time portion...Important point is that it must not show 23:59:59 of the previous day.

*(my emphasis)*

The simple way is always add a second, or even two. So it'd be 00:00:01 *(00:00:00 or later)* in the common case, and 00:00:00 *(not 23:59:59)* in the leap second case.

Comment: This would work(ish) but it's inelegant and if my application has events that happen between 00:00:00 and 00:00:01 then these will be incorrectly reported as having occurred on the wrong day. Not the end of the world, but I feel we can do better! Agreed thought that the "all singing, all dancing" approach is probably not the right way to go (because no libraries seem to do it that way so I would have to roll my own).

Comment: @tonicsoft: Well, you did say "00:00:00 or later." With the constraints as given in the question, it seems to me this *is* an elegant solution. If you want it to be exactly at 00:00:00, that's not the constraint given in the question.

Comment: @tonicsoft A time happening between 00:00:00 and 00:00:01 is NOT on previous day, at least not within context of java.time-package or older Java-Date-API. All its formatting stuff will then never display previous day. Of course, if the underlying clock follows any kind of smearing algorithm which might fulfill the smearing on NEXT day then this is something Java cannot observe (because here the leap second is hidden from you). So there is nothing you can do unless you try to avoid such a leap smearing algorithm ie. try to avoid such a clock.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the resulting discussions it seems clear that, in general, it is unwise to rely on your scheduler to run a task at the "correct" time if "wall time" is important to you. This is also true when running daily tasks at the same "wall time" across daylight savings shifts, although unlike the leap second case, the daylight savings case is well supported by existing tools (by Quartz for example).

Instead I think the best approach for such "wall time sensitive" processes is that when the task is run, check the system clock at that point. If your schedule was inaccurate for whatever reason (leap seconds are not the only time your system clock is adjusted relative to the elapsed time measured by `System.nanoTime()`) and the time has not yet been reached, then do nothing and reschedule the task for the correct time. This approach would also work for schedules that respond to daylight savings changes but as mentioned above this is already supported by common tools.

This approach was inspired by the comment by Jonathon Reinhart above. Rescheduling rather than sleeping though seems better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your concrete `ScheduledExecutorService`-implementation relies on `System.nanoTime()` (as you said) and taking into account your requirement/configuration that the initial delay parameter of the method [schedule(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) counts the elapsed milliseconds until next midnight including a possible leap second,

I suggest you to **use a leap-second-aware solution**. An example using my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) shows how to calculate the delay parameter:

```
Moment now = SystemClock.currentMoment(); // should not be called during a leap second
Moment nextMidnight =
    now.with(
        PlainTime.COMPONENT.setToNext(PlainTime.midnightAtStartOfDay()).in(
            Timezone.ofSystem().with(
                GapResolver.NEXT_VALID_TIME.and(OverlapResolver.EARLIER_OFFSET)
            )
        )
    );
long delayInMilliseconds = SI.NANOSECONDS.between(now, nextMidnight) / 1_000_000;
```

This code will also choose the earliest valid local time after midnight in case of daylight-saving-change (standard-Java would rather push the time forward by the size of the gap possibly resulting in a local time later than first valid time). For most zones, this is only relevant if choosing an arbitrary start time after midnight (dependent on business requirements).

What so ever, you should also care about connecting your systems to the same NTP-clock. Either you rely on OS-NTP-configuration, or you can use a Java-based clock connecting to NTP (Time4J offers here a [solution](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/clock/SntpConnector.html), too).

If your chosen clock is just doing arbitrary jumps (i.e. if someone has manually adjusted it or in case of bad NTP-configuration) then rescheduling the task after having checked the local walltime again is probably safer. However, I still think that calculating the delay parameter by Time4J-code above is a good idea because the chance to match midnight is higher than just to run the task and rechecking the local time.

You could also combine both approaches: exact calculation of delay AND check/reschedule.